# Problem with testing custom booster on local SAP BTP server

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform

In general, my goal is to use the local server to test new Boosters before opening a PR. For that, it is required to have the Boosters displayed. Therefore, I have done the local setup guide for the SAP BTP Cockpit (https://pages.github.tools.sap/cp-cockpit/cockpitDocs/development/prerequisites/local-development-setup/). The local server itself works, however, no Booster can be displayed “due to an internal server error”. Though, the existing boosters should be displayed. Instead, there is the message:

> Boosters cannot be displayed due to an internal server error

Does somebody know why the boosters are not displayed in the local server?

I followed the instructions of the local setup guide (https://pages.github.tools.sap/cp-cockpit/cockpitDocs/development/prerequisites/local-development-setup/).
I also specified a global "staging" account on the SAP BTP Control Center (https://cp-control-client-uc2.cfapps.stagingaws.hanavlab.ondemand.com/index.html). With that, the local server runs.

However, the boosters are not displayed.